# Toshiba laptop takes forever to get past UEFI

Tags: linux, windows-10, uefi

The computer is a Satellite S55t-B5233. Fairly recently I installed Arch Linux on a flash drive using this computer and since then (I'm quite sure this problem began afterward, though I'm not 100% sure.) the laptop will remain at a black screen when turning on, sometimes for as long as 20 minutes before the Toshiba logo screen appears. Shortly thereafter Windows starts to boot (I am using Windows 10). After it starts up everything works perfectly normally.

**The strangest thing is that if I open and close the laptop lid a couple times, Windows will start booting right away.**

There are a few things I can think of:

- During installation of Arch, I accidentally flagged one of the partitions on the hard disk as the EFI partition instead of the partition on the flash drive. However, I reverted this and there is only one EFI partition if I look in the Windows partition editor.
- After installing the Anniversary Update, the problem seemed to disappear for a boot or two, but now it has reappeared. I have not booted Arch during this time.
- I had set USB to have boot priority over the hard drive when installing Arch. However, I reverted this.
- This problem never occurs when booting Arch from the flash drive.
- Using `efibootmgr`, I noticed that there seemed to be two boot entries in the NVRAM for the flash drive. However, one may have been automatically created when booting from the flash drive. Here is the output:

`BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0003,2001,2003,2002
Boot0000* EFI USB Device (Lexar   USB Flash Drive)
Boot0001* Realtek PXE
Boot0002* Realtek PXE
Boot0003* Windows Boot Manager
Boot2001* EFI USB Device
Boot2003* EFI Network`

Any suggestions? Should I try reflashing the UEFI, booting from the network to check on that strange USB boot entry (as far as I know, Windows won't let you check EFI variables)..? Thanks.

Comment: "or something like that" - Please provide specific details.  Statements like "or something like that" are not specific enough.

Comment: I added the output of efibootmgr.

Comment: Have you checked for firmware updates from Toshiba? Might also look at the changelog on it if there is one.

Comment: It's on the latest firmware version available. However, I think I now have an idea of the cause of the problem. For some time now, the webcam hasn't been working unless I slowly close and partially open the lid—I think there's a loose connection with the webcam that's causing the UEFI to go crazy when it can't detect it. I may try to fix this at some point and I'll post an answer if it works.